# htaccess re-direct help - /dir1 but dont redirect /dir1/{anything}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried really hard to get this working, but after pulling my hair out and trying lots of re-direct rules and stuff I've ground to a halt, please help thanks!

Basically, I'm trying to redirect the following URL:
http://example.com/sub1 TO http://example.com/newsub1

(NOTE: I've had to take the 'http:// out of the links below as Stackoverflow will not let me post so many links!!)

BUT WHEN A SUB-DIRECTORY OF /sub1 IS REQUESTED, I need this to still be accessible and not change the URL - so I'm trying to keep this:

example.com/sub1/sub2

My rewrite rules keep re-writing example.com/newsub1/sub2

The issue I have is that in the above example /sub2 needs to be a wildcard - it's not a fixed url but dynamic and I need the scope for this to be anything.

So in summary:

1) example.com/sub1 -> REDIRECT -> example.com/newsub1

2) example.com/sub1/{could-be-anything} -> NO REDIRECT/RE-WRITE -> example.com/sub1/{could-be-anything}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see if this does what you want? I tested it here and it worked, but not sure what the rest of your file structure is like regarding trailing slashes and default files, nor whether something like  http://example.com/sub1/helloworld.php should be redirected or not:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub1/?$ /newsub1$1
```

Can be tweaked if needed, let me know.

**Edit:** That method was leaving an annoying – albeit harmless – doubleslash at the end. Thought about it a bit more and this is better I think:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule folder1/?$ /folder2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: NICE! Thanks - this worked for me
`RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub1/?$ /newsub1$1`

This successfully re-directs http://example.com/sub1 -> http://example.com/sub1 whist still maintaining access to http://example.com/sub1/other - which is exactly what I needed - good work!

I was effectively trying to get rid of access to a specific archive view in WordPress (/sub1), whilst still maintaining access to individual posts (/sub1/post-title) - and this has worked great - incidentally the second bit of code didn't do it for me, but the first shot you had did - thank you buddy ;)

Comment: I noticed my comment above was slightly wrong and I can't edit it now ;( Just for clarification if anyone else reads this in the future, `RewriteEngine On RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub1/?$ /newsub1$1` successfully redirects example.com/sub1 -> example.com/sub2 whilst still maintaining access to example.com/sub1/{anystring}